# Writing a JUnit Rule: Description doesn't contain my annotation

Tags: java, junit, annotations, rule

I'm trying to write a simple JUnit Rule implementation which reruns a test case a given amount of times if not successful.

It works fine as such, but I'd like to make it configurable per method with a custom annotation I attach to the method.

Here's my rule implementation:

```
public class Retry implements TestRule {
    private int retryCount = 10;

    @Override
    public Statement apply(Statement base, Description description) {
        return new Statement() {
            public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
                RetryCount annotation = description.getAnnotation(RetryCount.class);
                // Problem is here, the annotation is always null!
                int retries = (annotation != null) ? annotation.retries() : retryCount;

                // keep track of the last failure to include it in our failure later
                AssertionError lastFailure = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < retries; i++) {
                    try {
                        // call wrapped statement and return if successful
                        base.evaluate();
                        return;
                    } catch (AssertionError err) {
                        lastFailure = err;
                    }
                }
                // give meaningful message and include last failure for the
                // error trace
                throw new AssertionError("Gave up after " + retries + " tries", lastFailure);
            }
        };
    }

    // the annotation for method-based retries
    public static @interface RetryCount {
        public int retries() default 1;
    }
}
```

In the line I commented, I don't get the annotation I attach to the method:

```
public class UnreliableServiceUnitTest {
    private UnreliableService sut = new UnreliableService();

    @Rule
    public Retry retry = new Retry();

    @Test
    @RetryCount(retries=5) // here it is
    public void worksSometimes() {
        boolean worked = sut.workSometimes();
        assertThat(worked, is(true));
    }
}
```

If I debug into the Rule, the `Description` annotation list contains the `@Test` annotation but not the `@RetryCount`. I also tried adding a `@Deprecated` which will also get added.

Any idea why?

For completeness, this is the sample SUT:

```
public class UnreliableService {
    private static Random RANDOM = new Random();

    // needs at least two calls
    private static int COUNTER = RANDOM.nextInt(8) + 2;

    public boolean workSometimes() {
        if (--COUNTER == 0) {
            COUNTER = RANDOM.nextInt(8) + 2;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@Test` annotation is a Runtime annotation. Your `RetryCount` is not defined like that. It should be so you can access it during runtime. Change your code to this:

```
// the annotation for method-based retries
@Retention(value=RUNTIME)
public static @interface RetryCount {
    public int retries() default 1;
}
```

Using RetentionPolicy Runtime allows you to read the annotations reflectively. See [here the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that fixed it. Simple enough, wish it was mentioned in the `Description#getAnnotation` javadoc, but maybe it's obvious to people who are more used to writing annotations.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that it should be mentioned somewhere. But it is one of the things that you then never forget after you get it right once :)